# Strange behavior of just one @OneToOne property after migrating to SpringBoot 3.0 and Hibernate 6.1.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

After the migration, only one relationship just stopped working for me. Other similar things are working.

So, I have such a relationship. in which, if I get an account with user and billing, user is avialable, and the billing is null.
If I pull out the billing by account id, the billing is there.

```
//Account
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Billing billing = new Billing();


//Billing
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    private Account account;


//User
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;
```

To get account, such a query is executed. If you run it from the console, then the billing ID is also there.

```
[Hibernate] 
    /* <criteria> */ select
        a1_0.id,
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.account_id,
        b1_0.created,
        b1_0.last_modified,
        a1_0.created,
        a1_0.last_modified 
    from
        account a1_0 
    left join
        user u1_0 
            on a1_0.id=u1_0.account_id 
    left join
        billing b1_0 
            on a1_0.id=b1_0.account_id 
    where
        u1_0.id=?
```

What was I trying to do?

I tried to change "Naming strategy" https://thorben-janssen.com/sequence-naming-strategies-in-hibernate-6/

Created a clean database.

Nothing helped.

Who has any ideas? What could be the problem?

Comment: What did you change/upgrade. Doyou use the correct annotations. Why is there a `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on both ends of the relationship. Why the `new Billing()` that shouldn't be there. All in all there is too little information here I would say.

Comment: I deleted both `Cascade.ALL` and the creation of a `new object`, still Entity Billing was not there. From my point of view, these annotations are probably a redandant, but they should not play any serious role. Because it worked before.
Updated SpringBoot from `2.7.2 to 3.0.0`.
If I'm not mistaken, then from Hibernate `5.6.0` to `6.1.5`

Comment: If you updated you should also have changed the annotations. Could you show the dependencies and probably the full entities.

Comment: Only Package anmes from javax to jakarta

Comment: With the given query I would expect billing to be available and not `User` as `b1_0` references the billing stuff. I would also suggest to use `@MapsId` instead of using `@JoinColumn` (see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). But as request could you include your dependencies, full entities, repository and how you are running this?

Answer (score 0):

@m-deinum here

```
Entities:
@Entity(name = "account")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Billing billing;

    @CreatedDate
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "last_modified", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;
}

@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @CreatedDate
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "last_modified", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

}

@Entity(name = "billing")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Billing {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @CreatedDate
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "last_modified", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;
}
```

I am using Spring Data JPA Repositories. Standard `accountRepository.findById(2L)` or `findAccountByUserId` - the same result. User is there but not billing.

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"billing"})
    Optional<Account> findAccountByUserId(long id);
}
```

Dependencies:
Only SpringBoot Dependencies and ecpecially SB version: `3.0.0`. `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`(there is `hibernate-core:6.1.5`)